# electronJS / OSX - open file with my application, how to use the Apple event?

Tags: javascript, macos, electron, appleevents

My application is an Electron.js app

I type this command in the terminal to open a file with my app:

```
open "/Users/Bob/Pictures/test.jpg" -a myApp
```

In my `process.argv` I get an Apple event, something like '-psn_0_#######', How do I use this event to get the jpg?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On windows you parse `process.argv` (in the main process) to get the filepath. but on mac you need to listen to the 'open-file' event. This can be done like this:

```
app.on('will-finish-launching', () => {
    app.on('open-file', (event, path) => {
        // do something
    });
});
```

https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/app.md#event-open-file-macos